# Can the word "that" be substituted for in which?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, relative-clauses, clauses, adverbials

> Have you filled out the details in the paper that the date wasn't mentioned.

Is this a correct sentence?

Here I used "that" because I read in a grammar book "that" is sometimes used as an adverbial accusative = in which, on which, at which

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to say in your sentence. But no, _that_ does not work there unless you add another preposition. You suggest "in which"...so maybe stick an "in" after "mentioned".

Comment: In my grammar book It's written the word "that" is sometimes used as an adverbial accusative giving it the meaning of "on which", "at which", "in which"

Comment: Please provide the pertinent information, the source, and more context.

Comment: It's in my book. Do you want me to DM a pic of it?

Comment: We prefer that you take the time to type out the section. OCR do not  scan images. What is the name of the text?

Comment: Anyway, the answer is that _that_ can't be used as a substitute for _in which_. Prepositions aren't allowed with _that_. But it can substitute for the _which_ or _who_ or _whom_ in relative clauses (though not the ones in questions).